# Are non-exported packages still accessible from the unnamed module?

Tags: java, module, package, module-info

I am trying to restrict access to a package in my Java application using `module-info.java`.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I have the packages `org.test.a`, `org.test.b` and this `module-info.class`:

```java
module test {
    exports org.test.a;    
}
```

I then compile that, install the artifact to my local repository and import it in a second project.
There, I am still able to access classes of both packages `org.test.a` and `org.test.b`, even though only `org.test.a` should be accessible.

Only when I modularize that project (by adding a module-info.java that requires the `test` module), I can no longer compile it:

```
java: package org.test.b is not visible
  (package org.test.b is declared in module test, which does not export it)
```

Is it not possible to restrict package access to applications that are part of the "unnamed module", or am I just doing something wrong?

I am a bit confused, because even as part of the unnamed module, I am not able to access classes of unexported packages from the jdk (such as jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe).

Comment: No, the unnamed module does _not_ have access to non-exported packages. But if a module is placed on the class-path instead of the module-path, then it becomes part of the unnamed module and all `module-info` directives become meaningless. JDK modules are part of the run-time image, and thus are always on the module-path (i.e., are resolved as _named_ modules).

Comment: Is there any way to make sure that my library is always loaded on the module-path (when using maven / gradle)?